# HttpWebRequest work on .NetFramework but don't work on .NetCore

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

write some code(headers for webrequest), that perfectly work on .NetFramework app, but when i'm move it to .NetCore it brokes.
Code for .NetFramework

```
            WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(host, Convert.ToInt32(value));
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(HOST);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
            httpWebRequest.Host = HOST;
            httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "okhttp/3.12.1";
            httpWebRequest.Proxy = proxy;
```

Code for .NetCore

```
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(HOST);
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
            httpWebRequest.Host = HOST;
            httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "okhttp/3.12.1";
            httpWebRequest.Proxy = proxy;
            httpWebRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Problem that .NetFramework version send request without problems, but verson on .NetCore get 403 error. Can someone help?

after some debugging

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
 sw.Write(jsonBody);
}
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse(); //403 here
```

Comment: Use something like Fiddler to see any difference in the actual request sent

Comment: @stuartd Fiddler and others can't capture anything here :(

Comment: Check `ServicePoint` properties.

Comment: I see two different code blocks. Did you try exatly the same code before blaming .NET Core?

Comment: _Fiddler and others can't capture anything here_ - why?

Comment: @aepot yes, this was first think that i do

Comment: @stuartd idk, this requests just not show in it